# Checkbox not getting checked when using jquery toggle

Tags: jquery

I want the checkbox to be checked when I am using jquery toggle function.  It works fine when I use the `.bind('click')`.

```
$('#chkb').toggle(function () {

    $('#va').text("checked");
    $('#chkb').attr('checked', 'checked');

}, 
function () {

    $('#chkb').attr('checked', 'false');
    $('#va').text("");

});
```

html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkb" />
```

How do I get it done.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: How about this guys  :     var apchk = '<input type=checkbox checked="checked" id="chkb">';
             $('#c').html(apchk);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you really have to `checked` it in code? (Is there something I missed? checkbox when clicked, already toggle it's checked attribute value.)

Better way to do this is by using change like this,

```
$('#chkb').change(function () {
    var self = this;
    $('#va').text(function(i,text){
        return self.checked?"checked":"";
    });
})
```

Comment: You can check a checkbox with the keyboard, too.

Comment: ahh... so better to use `.change()` then. ;)

Comment: What about this   var apchk = '<input type=checkbox checked="checked" id="chkb">';
             $('#c').html(apchk);

Comment: @Jean - Why? what's with that?

Comment: @reigel well that is one way I just found out before I checked out the solutions here

Comment: @Jean - and that did the trick you need? Cause honestly, I don't get that. ^_^

Comment: I don't get the "var apchk" thing either, this solution looks up '#va' each change, better to stick it in a variable ... ?

Comment: Yes, it worked. now I have another problem, $('#va').text(""); does not work.  I put the checkbox between <div></div> and did a .html().

Comment: Your first code doesn't work (in Chrome), and I'm not sure why not. ==> http://jsfiddle.net/9YShm/ ----- The lettering changes, but it always looks unchecked. ----- It works with change.

Comment: @Jean - Why don't you edit the HTML into the question? (I mean included the `<div></div>` too.

Comment: @Peter - I've never tested it as to it looks right. But now, I will ask SO, don't really know the cause of it.

Comment: With the .html() it works in chrome.  The code in the question does not work in chrome ...

Comment: @NimChimpsky - the erased one did not work. IMHO, it is rude just down-voting without giving the poster to explain first it's view.

Comment: you posted code that didn't work - whats the big deal ? fine its erased now, but it wasn't at the time, it was presented as working valid code. If thats not worth a down vote I don't know what is.

Comment: @Nim - haha nevermind. Arguing like this won't help Jean at all.

Comment: Lol. True. TBH I would have thought the erased code would have worked, , but I need me some points too ... :-)  jQuery is great, saves me so much time.

Comment: Its interesting though, the code in the question does not work!

Comment: @Jean - about `.toggle()` on checkbox, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837844/checkbox-with-toggle)

Answer (score 2):

```
chkb = $('#chkb');
va = $('#va');

chkb.change(function () {
   va.text(chkb[0].checked ? "checked" : "");
});
```

Caching selectors into variables speeds things up - doesn't have to search the dom each time. Putting `chkb` into a variable means it can be used elsewhere in your jQuery, instead of using `this`.

Comment: +1 ^_^ one comment though. Although jQuery helps you a lot, don't abuse it. `chkb[0].checked` is faster than `chkb.is(':checked')`. cheers!

Comment: yeah and a down-vote won't help. ;) Just some explanation and all of us are happy. ;)