# Checkbox with toggle() breaking the checked/unchecked state

Tags: jquery

can anyone spread some light?

Why this `.toggle()` is breaking the checked/unchecked state of a checkbox?

```
$('#checkbox').toggle(function(){},function(){});​
```

when I think, it's just doing nothing.

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5P56s/)

<sub>this was taken from comments of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837390/checkbox-not-getting-checked-when-using-jquery-toggle/3837448#3837448)</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toggle()` called with two callbacks adds a `click` event on the targeted element. The event will execute the first callback on even clicks; the second one on odd ones.

Also, and this is why it changes the behaviour, according to the [manual:](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

> The implementation also calls .preventDefault() on the event, so links will not be followed and buttons will not be clicked if .toggle() has been called on the element.